# Contador de visitas se resetea solo

Tags: php

Buenas,

Uso una forma muy simple de contar el número de visitas que tengo a diferentes noticias. Cada vez que hace hace una petición a la noticia en MySQL le sumo una visita, y actualizo la entrada en la base de datos.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art WHERE id = :id");
$statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$posts = $statement->fetch();

$visitas = $posts['visitas'];
$visitas++;

$statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE art SET visitas = :visitas WHERE id = $id");
$statement->execute(array(':visitas' => $visitas));
```

Funcionar funciona bien, pero desde febrero se me han reseteado los valores en 3 ocasiones. La primera me puso el campo visitas de todas las noticias a 800, las dos siguientes ocasiones a 0, hoy es la última vez que me ha pasado.

¿A qué se debe? No entiendo el motivo por el que pasa, el resto de campos no se alteran en absoluto.

El campo visitas en la base de datos es de tipo `int(11)`.

Comment: Recibes el número de visitas por post?? porque? No es un buen diseño, pero puedes hacer un `UPDATE art SET visitas = visitas+1 WHERE id = $id` y te evitas cualquier POST mal construido

Comment: @DavidIsla Pensaba que era necesario primero recoger el valor del campo visitas, hacer la suma, y actualizar el valor, ese es el motivo por el que lo recogía con post después de hacer la consulta. He probado lo que comentas y funciona igual, pero sigo sin entender porqué se reestablece el campo visitas.

Comment: Los motivos @jetlagfox pueden ser muchos, piensa incluso que dos usuarios pulsando refrescar al mismo tiempo, pudieran enviarte el mismo contador y tu tan sólo aumentar 1. Es mejor que lo realice la BBDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te recomiendo obtener el valor para posteriormente incrementarlo. Podría darse el caso de pérdida de visitas: dos usuarios que visitan a la vez el sitio, ambos reciben el mismo valor actual, ambos lo incrementan en uno y ambos escriben el mismo valor en la base de datos, perdiéndose uno de ellos.

Te recomiendo obtener el valor actual tras haberlo actualizado de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Primero incrementamos el valor de las visitas */
$statement = $conexion->prepare('
  UPDATE art SET visitas = visitas + 1 WHERE id = :id
');
$statement->execute([
  ':id' => $id]
);

/* Ahora obtenemos el contador para mostrarlo */
$statement = $conexion->prepare('
  SELECT *
  FROM art
  WHERE id = :id
');
$statement->execute([':id' => $id]);
$posts = $statement->fetch();

$visitas = $posts['visitas'];
```

Las actualizaciones del tipo `SET visitas = visitas + 1` se ejecutan de manera atómica, por lo que no se perderá ninguna visita a la página y no cabe la posibilidad de reseteo a no ser que llegue al límite de la capacidad del tipo de campo usado para almacenar el número de visitas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a ambos! Entiendo que la parte de obtener el valor de las visitas es opcional, en este caso sólo quiero actualizar el valor de las visitas "en segundo plano".

Comment: Claro, es completamente opcional. Pensé que necesitabas mostrarlo al lado del mensaje (con un mensaje del tipo "visto N veces" o similar).