# Campo en MySQL se re-establece solo en todas las entradas

Tags: php, mysql

Hace más de un año me encontré por primera vez con este problema, en una tabla que tengo en mi base de datos donde tengo todos los artículos de mi proyecto, el valor de uno de los campos se re-estableció a 0, el de todas y cada una de las entradas que tenía.

Este campo no es más que un contador de visitas, donde cada vez que se accede al artículo suma el valor en una unidad de esta forma:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE art SET visitas = visitas + 1 WHERE id = :id');
$statement->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

Esta solución la obtuve de una [consulta previa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72030/contador-de-visitas-se-resetea-solo). Pero el problema ha vuelto a ocurrir en dos ocasiones en el último mes. El tipo de dato de este campo en la base de datos es int(11), no sé si eso podría tener algo que ver. El resto de los campos se mantienen inalterables.

Comment: Esa consulta es inocua para el resto de campos y, además, se ejecuta de manera atómica (no es posible que se corrompa el contenido por actualizaciones concurrentes), de modo que lo único que puede restablecer el contenido de ese campo es otro `UPDATE` de esa misma tabla o un `REPLACE` (que elimina y regenera el registro). ¿Tienes acceso al log de transacciones del servidor MySQL?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, pues en realidad no lo sé porque no lo he usado nunca. Pero he mirado el código que tengo y aunque tengo más de un `UPDATE`, el resto son para otras tablas. Las única que uso en la tabla de los artículos son 2 por tener artículos en ingles y llevar también la contabilidad de las visitas por separado.

Comment: Por un lado, para depurar en qué momento se restablece el campo, necesitarás activar el log binario (si no lo tienes activado ya) para que se guarden todas las modificaciones en los archivos `binlog.*`. Posteriormente podrás analizar los cambios con la herramienta [`mysqlbinlog`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) y ver qué consulta modificó ese valor y junto qué `UPDATE` fue modificado.

Comment: Por otro lado, deberás consultar TODOS los `UPDATE`s que hagas, y no sólo en ese archivo PHP, si no en todos los demás. A veces una modificación no deseada en una tabla suele ser efecto de una consulta SQL olvidada en alguna parte del código. Si usas un ORM o una clase que encapsule toda la funcionalidad te será fácil depurar esto y, además, impedirlo. Pero si usas código propio distribuido en multitud de archivos PHP te será más difícil encontrar el origen de este tipo de problemas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia He consultado a mi proveedora de hosting y por lo que me han comentado no tengo la opción activada.

Comment: Si es un hosting compartido entonces puedes ir olvidando las herramientas de análisis del log de transacciones, porque ni tan siquiera podrás ejecutarlas. ¿Tienes tareas planificadas o scripts que se ejecuten de manera periódica? Está claro que hay una consulta que restablece el valor por defecto del campo o le cambia el valor. Busca también consultas `INSERT` que tengan un `ON DUPLICATE KEY` que modifiquen el contenido de un registro si éste ya existe previamente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia No es compartido, lo puedo activar pero no controlo de este tema y no sé si va a ser mejor el remedio que el problema.

Comment: No es un remedio. Es una forma de auditar todo lo que pasa en la base de datos. La reducción de rendimiento es inapreciable, aunque sí que aumentará el uso en disco dependiendo del número de logs que quieras mantener y del número de actualizaciones que se generen en la base de datos. Es decir, activarlo te facilita averiguar qué consulta es la que cambia esos campos, pero no te dirá qué script PHP o conexión desde phpmyadmin o cualquier otro GUI ha generado dicha consulta.. pero es un comienzo ya que también sabrás a qué hora se hizo, etc. Echa un vistazo a las páginas que te facilité.